# Have session send and receive data after browser is closed. .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a way to have a session send and receive data in intervals even after the user has closed their browser? We have members that signup and sometimes not receive a confirmation code due to a lost request to retrieve that code from our server that generates it.

My thought is to have the session try to retrieve that code for up to 4 hours in 30 minute intervals. If not, it will send an email to the member letting them know they need to signup again.

Is this possible with sessions? We are using .NET

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the session"? Are you anticipating this being something at the user's end or some process on your server?

Comment: In that scenario you'd want to make the request that fires the email as quick as possible. For example, you could have it just add the user/email to a list in memory instead of firing the email then, periodically read from that list and send emails via some other service/mechanism

Comment: @Chris By session I mean using session variables to resubmit data until our server returns a confirmation number. As it stands, the confirmation code can sometimes be blank and not accounted for at all. The submission gets lost.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of the web being disconnected you web pages/views should should show data and post data back back on user interaction where the the most immediate functions do what they need to do quickly. For instance if a user signs up to your service they are presented with a signup page, when the commit that page their details should be saved any further actions should not be done on that page and any operation needs to assume that browser could close at any time. If a user submits the signup form you should save their details.. anything else like email notifications etc should happen after that. To enable this simply, you could use something like HangFire (https://www.hangfire.io) to monitor signups and send emails using a background process.. (you could trigger this at the time as part of your signup method or have a recurring task to check signups) the key point being that the long running task like constructing and sending an email will be done outside the page request.

Comment: I can definitely implement another method to accomplish this task. And for the most part that is how the current process is setup. I suppose i'm trying to create a safety net, just in case we didn't get a confirmation code without having the user needing to go back and try again.

I was wondering if its possible to use a user's session hours after they left their browser and do some processing.

Thanks for the quick response!